# How to add column that adds new row for each existing row

Tags: r

I have two data frames, df1 and df2, and would like to merge them to form df3, as shown below. I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I have been unable to find a straight forward solution.

```
df1 = data.frame(id = c(1,2), Name = c('Bob', 'Sue'), stringsAsFactors = F)
id | Name 
==========
1 |   Bob 
2 |   Sue 

df2 = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), year = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004))
id | year
==========
1 |   2001 
2 |   2002 
3 |   2003 
4 |   2004

df3 =
id | Name | year
=================
1 |   Bob | 2001
2 |   Bob | 2002
3 |   Bob | 2003
4 |   Bob | 2004
5 |   Sue | 2001
6 |   Sue | 2002
7 |   Sue | 2003
8 |   Sue | 2004
```

Comment: Could you explain the need for the `id` column please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `merge(df1, df2, by=NULL)` for a cartesian product
See here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/merge

Comment: Great! That's exactly the type of solution I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @John If this it the best answer to your question, you can mark it as "accepted" (hit the check-mark next to the up-/down-arrows on its left). This will show everyone that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `crossing`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossing(df1, df2) %>%
   transmute(id = row_number(), Name, year)
#  id Name year
#1  1  Bob 2001
#2  2  Bob 2002
#3  3  Bob 2003
#4  4  Bob 2004
#5  5  Sue 2001
#6  6  Sue 2002
#7  7  Sue 2003
#8  8  Sue 2004
```

---

It seems the 'id' column in the output has nothing to do with the initial 'id' columns in the dataset.  In that case, do the `crossing` without the 'id' column and then create the 'id' as `row_number()`

```
crossing(df1[-1], df2[-1]) %>% 
        mutate(id = row_number())
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:2, Name = c("Bob", "Sue")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, year = 2001:2004), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use: `expand.grid(Name = df1$Name, year = df2$year)`

That gives:

```
  Name year
1  Bob 2001
2  Sue 2001
3  Bob 2002
4  Sue 2002
5  Bob 2003
6  Sue 2003
7  Bob 2004
8  Sue 2004
```